# What's a good (free) client for Informix on Windows?

Tags: windows, client, informix

I'm looking for a GUI client for Informix on Windows (mainly to view data and execute queries), free would obviously be nice but I know Informix is used mostly in corporate environments and free may not be available. Perhaps the best option is set up ODBC and use any one of many clients available?

Comment: What are you wanting to do in this GUI client? Manage the database server or write queries? That would help in answering the question.

Comment: mainly write queries/view data. (db server management would be nice extras, though.)

Comment: For the record: Stackexchange as a network of sites has a policy of ["no shopping questions"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and so I'm going to encourage that here as well. Had the question been "what are the pitfalls of using these three products for Informix on Windows to access my data" then that would be a perfectly cromulent question. As it is, this is a little too open ended and vague. Therefore, I feel compelled to close it. Stackexchange sites are not for shopping questions, even tho there is "specific expertise" involved.

Comment: you missed one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/755/whats-a-good-free-client-for-oracle-8-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: I finally found a good client (with free version): http://www.serverstudio.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest SQuirreL (free) but [Informix doesn't appear to be supported](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=faq#faq0)

A Google search shows some older pages though so YMMV

Comment: It does support Informix now. Check out that link again.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net) it's a Java/JDBC based query tool similar to SQuirrel.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) with Informix for a long time. It is also Java/JDBC based. However, it can be quite expensive.